# A standard approach for disabling UI when application state changes

Tags: iphone, ios, user-experience, external-accessory

I have an iOS application that works with an external accessory connected through the dock connector.   It is possible that the device may become disconnected during use of the application.

We have a Windows application that uses the same device and a message that says "Device Disconnected" on a partially opaque white background (so the view still shows through) when something like this occurs.  When the device is plugged back in the message disappears.

Is an approach like this appropriate on iOS or is there a standard way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is not functional w/o the connected device i can't see why Apple would be against the warning and blocked UI.

I'd not block the **static** UI completely not to give the impression of the hanged application. You can either add some simple animation or add the `info` button to avoid it.

Two options to do it:

1. simple for a single-window apps, a little dirty, very fast to implement:

   > add the blocker view over the application `key window`
2. doesn't depend on windows usage, clean, not so fast and could be hard to keep organized

   > extend your navigation view controller  (UINavigation controller or UITabBarController) or every viewController separately with such functionality.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of #2. There are certain views in the app that require the device to be online to be useful and others can be used independently of the device.  It's a tabbed application and the user would still be able to navigate to other views at any time.

Comment: @rhooligan Do you mean it depends completely on the selected tab and there's no tab with the content partially usable without the connected device ?

Comment: There are 3 tabs in the app.  Each tab has multiple views. Two of the tabs are only useful when the accessory is connected.

Comment: @rhooligan then it's pretty easy a) to make the viewControllers to register for your notifications or b) to let the single `deviceManagerConnection` do it's job receiving notifications and updating your tabs. It will be important not to forget to make an additional state check at `viewWillAppear`. With #a you can use the property to store the overlapping view and have different views for different controllers, for #b it's easier to use the same overlapping view identifying it with tag. I'm not sure that approaches are initially compatible with the orientation changes, that needs to be checked.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've implemented a couple methods called disableView and enableView on the base ViewController for the varios accessory views.  It seems to work out nicely since the user can go back to what they were doing if they re-enable the accessory.